# C Language: Loop Text with Random Color Combination

Tags: c, text, colors, dev-c++

The following test fails because "system("color #code);" needs to be static.
For example:-

`system("color 0F");` Works.

`system("color %d %d",a, b);` Does Not.

Complete Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
char R[15]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    while(1)
    {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int Ra = rand() %10 + 6;
    int Rb = rand() %10 + 6;

    system("color %c%c",R[Ra], R[Rb]);  

    printf("Hello world!");
    system("cls");
    };

return 0;
}
```

How do I get this to work? Is there a better way?

Comment: What makes you think `system` is taking format strings? Use `sprintf`  instead and then feed the output to `system`.

Comment: Don't you just need to build the string with `sprintf()` before passing to `system()`?

Comment: BTW, `srand` needs to be called only once.

Comment: "System" doesn't understand variable input. 
I need a way to make my Text loop with random colors.

Comment: And your `R` array is one element short. (Your maximum possible random number is 15, which is one element beyond a 15-element array.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system()` doesn't take a formatted string.

Try this instead:

```
int main(void){

    char R[16]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    srand(time(NULL));
    char color_string[20];

    while(1) {

        int Ra = rand() %16;
        int Rb = rand() %16;

        sprintf(color_string, "color %c%c", R[Ra], R[Rb]);
        system(color_string);  

        printf("Hello world!");
        system("cls");
    };

    return 0;
}
```

With `getch()` (as asked, but not standard):

```
while( getch() != 27) {

    system("cls");

    int Ra = rand() %16;
    int Rb = rand() %16;

    sprintf(color_string, "color %c%c", R[Ra], R[Rb]);

    system(color_string);  

    printf("Hello world!");
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much... It has now been Solved!

Comment: @Errorising - You also didn't get al the possible colors - see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you indeed. I forgot that I excluded black for some reason.

Comment: Now I want this to work with a "while ( getch(); );" Please Help!

Comment: @Errorising - `getch()` is not standard, but I'll add it anyway.

Comment: I mean, I require a "Press any key to continue" thing.
That when pressed, it should move to the next phase.

That would mean it would Quit for this particular program.

Comment: @Errorising - See update - press a key to change color, press escape to exit.

Comment: Very nice. But I am trying to figure out a way to instead of pressing an "escape" key, it should continue with any key. Until then, continue to "Loop".

Comment: @Errorising - If you are on Windows/DOS, use  `while( !_kbhit() ) {`. - Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your (original) problem :)